# XSLT 1.0 amount fields have to have at least 2 decimals

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have two xmls.There is a amount field which can contains values like 54.2,54.23,54.234,54.234567.

Would someone please tell me how can I make sure that atleast two decimal places will appear in the output xml.Currently 54.2 gets converted to 54,2 , but I want it to be 54,20

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the format-number() function to convert a number into a string in a given format.
At least two decimal places will be appeared if you use this "#.00##########" format string.

If you have an xml file which can contains values like 54.2,54.23,54.234,54.234567:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
        <price>54.2</price>
        <price>54.23</price>
        <price>54.234</price>
        <price>54.234567</price>
</catalog>
```

You can convert the numbers with an xslt like this to get at least two decimal places

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
      <xsl:for-each select="/catalog/price">
             <xsl:value-of select='format-number(., "#.00##########")'/><br />
      </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then the output:

```
54.20
54.23
54.234
54.234567
```