# XML parse number in two decimal places

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi i have something like this in transform XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(g:price, ' PLN', ''))"/>
```

It returns number in format like this:

```
1 0 ACCEC002ECS034790000 89.0000
```

I want to get price in format: 89.00

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just to clarify... the expression you have shown only outputs the `89.0000` rather than the whole string you have shown? It might help if your showed a sample of your XML, especially the value of the `g:price` element. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `format-number`?  (I can't find another question that exactly matches this, but it's similar to [XSLT 1.0 amount fields have to have at least 2 decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578452/xslt-1-0-amount-fields-have-to-have-at-least-2-decimals))

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(normalize-space(translate(g:price, ' PLN', '')), #.00)"/>
```

Should work.